# How have a list inside a popup control in C#/XAML metro application?

Tags: silverlight, xaml, microsoft-metro, winrt-xaml

i would like to know :-

How to have a list inside a popup control in metro application ?

Please let me know how can i workaround this

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<Popup x:Name="popup">
<Grid  >
       <ListBox x:Name="listBox" />
</Grid>
</Popup>
```

Comment: i am showing up the popup but , i want to focus only on the popup , but it is not being focused , i want to open a popup and focus only on it in my metro application (i want to focus only on popup as it happnes in andriod). , can i do that here also in my metro application ?

Comment: i mean to say i want set focus only on the popup not on the other elements present that page , can we do it , please let me know . thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Why not try collapsing the visibility of the main grid when the popup is activated, or knock the opacity back to leave a ghost image behind the popup whilst calling IsHitTestVisible=false on the main grid to render it inactive.